# Recursively applying a substitution

Tags: recursion

I have an expression like this:

```
2v[j-1]-(s[j]+1)(c[j]-c[j-1]) >= v[j]
```

I want to apply this recursively say k times. I can do one step like this:

```
Expand[2v[j-1]-(s[j]+1)(c[j]-c[j-1]) >= v[j] /. v[j-1] -> 2v[j-2]-(s[j-1]+1)(c[j-1]-c[j-2])]
```

After doing a few more steps I can probably see the pattern. Is there some way of doing this automatically?

Comment: Look at the [Nest](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html) documentation (or [NestList](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html) if you want to see each step) 

Also your rule won't do anything past the first iteration, since you get rid of all occurrences of `v[j-1]`

Comment: Ah yes, I was not clear sorry. I want to get an inequality at depth k so ... 2^k*v[j-k] ... >= v[j]

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly sure if this is what you're getting at, but here's an attempt. it looks like you only want to recurse the definition of `v` on the left side of the inequality. We can build a helper function to do that.

```
RecurseV[expr_] := expr /. v[arg_] :> 2 v[arg - 1] - (s[arg] + 1) (c[arg] - c[arg - 1])
```

So then, something like this should be equivalent to your first step:

```
RecurseV[2 v[j - 1] - (s[j] + 1) (c[j] - c[j - 1])] >= v[j]
(* 2*(c[-2 + j] - c[-1 + j])*(1 + s[-1 + j]) + (c[-1 + j] - c[j])*(1 + s[j]) + 4*v[-2 + j] >= v[j] *)
```

As @ydd pointed out, you can now do this for some given number of steps using `Nest`. Here's 3 times:

```
Nest[RecurseV, 2 v[j - 1] - (s[j] + 1) (c[j] - c[j - 1]), 3] >= v[j]
```

Comment: This looks to give me exactly what I want. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You may do this using "Nest":

```
k = 4;
rule = v[j - 1] -> 2 v[j - 2] - (s[j - 1] + 1) (c[j - 1] - c[j - 2]);
Expand[
 
 Nest[# /. rule &,
  2 v[j - 1] - (s[j] + 1) (c[j] - c[j - 1]) >= v[j]
  , k]
 
 ]

2 c[-2 + j] - c[-1 + j] - c[j] + 2 c[-2 + j] s[-1 + j] - 
  2 c[-1 + j] s[-1 + j] + c[-1 + j] s[j] - c[j] s[j] + 4 v[-2 + j] >= 
 v[j]
```